# What is the complexity(Ø) of this pseudo code?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

My question is about finding the complexity of this algorithm. J value is related to n, so I'm confused about this.

What is the asymptotic complexity of this pseudocode?

```
for i=1 to n
  do
  j = 1;
  while (j < n)
    do
    j = j * 2;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think the complexity is? Have you tried small examples with paper and pencil or on the computer? As a hint: the outer loop variable isn't used, so the runtime is `n` times the runtime of the code inside loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is `O(n log2n)`

The outer loop is called `n` times and the inner loop is called `log2n` times, since in every iteration, `j` is doubled. For first iteration, i.e., `k=0`; `j` is equal to `1` and goes on like `2, 4, 8, ...` until `2k>=n`

Comment: The inner loop is constant

Comment: @codeaperature can you elaborate please? If it is constant, can you give me the constant value?

Answer (score -2):

If I add a print at the end of the inner loop, I see:

```
(1,2,5)
(1,4,5)
(1,8,5)
(2,2,5)
(2,4,5)
(2,8,5)
(3,2,5)
(3,4,5)
(3,8,5)
(4,2,5)
(4,4,5)
(4,8,5)
(5,2,5)
(5,4,5)
(5,8,5)
```

So it appears O(n^2) but the inner loop appears constant so probably O(n) -- If the `(j < n)` part is switched to `(j < i)`, that would be closer to O(n log(n)):

```
(2,2,5)
(3,2,5)
(3,4,5)
(4,2,5)
(4,4,5)
(5,2,5)
(5,4,5)
(5,8,5)
```